# Reading a process memory in linux

Tags: c++, c, linux

When reading a process memory, can you use the addresses recieved from `/proc/{pid}/maps` or do you need to use the addresses gotten from there in combination with `/proc/{pid}/mem` as offsets?

Comment: ASLR is going to give you grief I predict.

Comment: I'm making a memory scanner (alternative to scanmem), so all I'm doing is looking through the memory to find a specific address and then using that, so I don't think it should give me that much

Comment: As long as you are fine with the fact that all addresses will be different on every run of the program, I guess you are ok.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux

Comment: do you have any knowledge if that's faster or slower than using `process_vm_readv`?